# How to select a select type = multiple - jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

What is the best way to select ALL options that are in a `<select>` that is set as "multiple" ?

Comment: You want to find all `select` elements with `type="multiple"`? or find the selected option values?

Comment: I wanted to a select element with type multiple then from there I can grab all options by selecting them all (.attr("selected","selected"))

Answer (score 6):

Simple using the [Has Attribute Selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)...

```
$("select[multiple] option");
```

This checks for the existence of the `multiple` attribute on the select tag, and grabs all the options within it.

Comment: @Marko I have answered: what is the best way to select ALL options that are in a `select` that is set as "multiple"

Comment: It's an ambiguous question, I re-read it three times and up-voted both of you.

Comment: @Josh - it worked great. Didnt think of using that method for the select. Thanks for that.

Comment: Your original answer was `$("select[multiple]");`

Comment: @Coughlin You're welcome :)  Next time please re-read your question and make sure it is as clear as possible before hitting that magical Publish button.  Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

**From the jQuery documentation**

[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

The `.val()` method is primarily used to get the values of form elements. ***In the case of `<select multiple="multiple">` elements, the `.val()` method returns an array containing each selected option.***

To select *all* options just use `$("select option")` or to specifically target **multiple** use @Josh's answer `$("select[multiple] option");`

Comment: I don't know if this is what the OP wants.  In the question, it says "select ALL options".